# update old processes with the new process definition -Activiti

Tags: migration, activiti, business-process-management

I have some processes that ran with old process definitions. But due to requirement change the user task data has been updated with new attributes and this process definition has been deployed. I'm aware that "`SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd"` can be set to "yes" to point the processes to the new definition/version.

I would like to know how to migrate the old process data to have the newly added attributes of the user task updated in them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to migrate process instance data, however, when you set the version to the new process definition the instance data will go with the migrated instance.

What you have to be careful of is to make sure you include null checks for any of the data that may not be present in the migrated process instances.

Hope this helps,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no easy way for migration, however depending on the differences between the two definitions and to what extend you may *not* prefer to use `SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd`, you may find [DynamicBpmnService](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/DynamicBpmnService.html) useful when combined with detecting definitions' versions inside your logic.

And yes another way would be to use `SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd` but  be extra cautions for tasks that were actually active prior to migration, as Activiti's database model have *some* redundant data (some for [performance reasons](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/219057-data-model-review#comment-779797)), you are better studying the DB tables first for these tasks and then inspecting the before and after migration state. For example, keeping up with a simple changed attribute is much easier than an added boundary event on an active User Task, which affects the "execution tree".

I would also advice to compare `SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd`'s implementations between [Activiti](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/cmd/SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd.java) and [Camunda](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/cmd/SetProcessDefinitionVersionCmd.java), it is sad to have such enhancements efforts separated, but that is another story.